# Does Bharat Matha exist in hindu dieties?

Tags: history

Does [Bharat Matha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Mata) exist in hindu dieties or it was created for Indian Freedom Movement?

Comment: Bharat Mata is not just a deity, she is greater than that, a Mother. Just as how one worships the mother or father as a God, one worships the Mother India as a God. Similarly Mother Earth, Mother Nature, Mother Cow etc. So Bharat Mata need not exist in Hindu deities, it is simply an expression of Love for the land through which one is born. We are all here today, as who we are, only because of our Mother, Father, Our Land of Bharat, and so on. Thus it is only natural to respect and revere these as God Himself. All the best sir

Answer (score 5):

Bharat Mata is the metaphoric representation by Indian citizens towards their motherland India which is also called 'Bharat' in Hindi language. India, the country is being treated as a mother here as it performs the duties of a mother. The country as a mother, gives us food, shelter, atmosphere to live, protection, nurtures us, makes us learn different things, etc. Also, as a son/daughter has responsibility of taking care of their mother, similarly Indian citizens are motivated to take care and do everything possible for the betterment of the country. The word 'Motherland' is being used in English also in many countries to represent the same feelings of faith and duty between a country and countrymen.

Answer (score 3):

Bharat Mata is not actually a goddess, but a land where we live. It was named after King Bharat. Bharat has been a country for thousands of years. It has witnessed many wars with others such as Sri Lanka (Ravana), Greeks (Kalyavana), etc. People living in India have been bounded by Ramayana and Mahabharata from east to west as well as north to south. It might be true that the pictorial form of Bharat Mata is recent one, but Bharat mata has been since many millennia. Hence Arjun is called Bharatvanshaj (Descendant of Bharat) by Krishna. That is the reason why there are 52 shaktipeethas all spread across Bharat. Even Shankaracharya travelled whole country and placed peethas in the 4 directions.